# using values generated in main1() and using them in main2()

Tags: c, function, matrix, program-entry-point

if i have a program like shown below in c:

```
 void main1() {} /* Note that these aren't called main. */
 void main2() {}
  ...

 int main() {
            main1();
            main2();
            return 0;
            }
```

i have some values or can be a matrix which is made in main1(), and than i want to use this matrix in main2(). how can we transfer these values:
because i have to subfunctions of main and i have to generated a big matrix of unknown length in main1() and i have to use these matrix values in main2(). but i don't have any idea how can i do it? how can i store a matrix and use it in main2()?
thankyou:

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

1. Use a global variable to hold the matrix and define the size to be the maximum you expect.
2. If you do not like global variables, just wrap the matrix inside a structure and use that as parameter and return type.
3. Even better would be to use pointers and allocate/free memory dynamically.

Comment: yes i have allocated memorray dynamically and than i made the matrix. Now the problem rises when i have to use this matrix in other funtion. Because it requires a lot of computation to make this matrix so i dont want to use it again and again. i want to just copay the values of the matrix. I tried making globle variable array but it does not work. Because the values it stores just in that function. i hope u understand and clarify your answer. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Define a matrix struct pointer that holds your matrix, send a pointer to it to `main1()` allocate it and fill it and send it to `main2()`:

```
struct matrix;
void main1(struct matrix** ppmatrix) {} /* Note that these aren't called main. */
void main2(struct matrix* pmatrix) {}
  ...

int main() {
    struct matrix* pmatrix;
    main1(&pmatrix); // allocate and fill matrix struct
    main2(pmatrix);  // use matrix
    return 0;
}
```

This is the proper way to do it in C. in C++ you should pass these by reference.